# Find and highlight text in linux command line

Tags: linux, search, command-line-interface, highlight

I am looking for a linux command that searches a string in a text file,
and highlights (colors) it on every occurence in the file, WITHOUT omitting text lines (like grep does).

Comment: You mean like inside an editor?

Comment: It is not clear what you want. Simple text files have no colors and there is no way no highlight them unless it's done for a particular editor or changing their format (like turning them into HTML files or something similar).

Comment: try this answer: https://serverfault.com/a/180751/303828 but this only searches in command output. use `cat filename` as a command.

Answer (score 8):

I wrote this handy little script. It could probably be expanded to handle args better

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$1" == "" ]; then
    echo "Usage: hl PATTERN [FILE]..."
elif [ "$2" == "" ]; then
    grep -E --color "$1|$" /dev/stdin
else
    grep -E --color "$1|$" $2
fi
```

it's useful for stuff like highlighting users running processes:

```
ps -ef | hl "alice|bob"
```

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
tail -f yourfile.log | egrep --color 'DEBUG|'
```

where DEBUG is the text you want to highlight.

Answer (score 1):

`command | grep -iz -e "keyword1" -e "keyword2"`  (ignore -e switch if just searching for a single word, -i for ignore case, -z for treating as a single file)

Alternatively,while reading files
 grep -iz -e "keyword1" -e "keyword2" 'filename'

OR

`command | grep -A 99999 -B 99999 -i -e "keyword1" "keyword2"`  (ignore -e switch if just searching for a single word, -i for ignore case,-A and -B for no of lines before/after the keyword to be displayed)

Alternatively,while reading files

grep -A 99999 -B 99999 -i -e "keyword1" "keyword2" 'filename'

Answer (score 1):

command [ack](https://beyondgrep.com/) with `--passthru` switch:

```bash
ack --passthru pattern path/to/file
```

Answer (score 0):

I take it you meant "without omitting text lines" (instead of emitting)...

I know of no such command, but you can use a script such as this (this one is a simple solution that takes the filename (without spaces) as the first argument and the search string (also without spaces) as the second):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
ifs_store=$IFS;
IFS=$'\n';
for line in $(cat $1);
    do if [ $(echo $line | grep -c $2) -eq 0 ]; then
        echo $line;
    else
        echo $line | grep --color=always $2;
    fi
done
IFS=$ifs_store
```

save as, for instance colorcat.sh, set permissions appropriately (to be able to execute it) and call it as

```
colorcat.sh filename searchstring
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a requirement like this recently and hacked up a small program to do exactly this. [Link](https://gist.github.com/3977405)

Usage: `./highlight test.txt '^foo' 'bar$'`

Note that this is very rough, but could be made into a general tool with some polishing.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell `grep` to use color highlighting and show lots of context:

```
grep --color -C 1000000 pattern file.txt
```

`-C n` or `--context=n` tells `grep` to show up to `n` lines before and after the match. Be aware that setting `n` to several billion will make `grep` use lots of CPU and run slow, so choose a "reasonably huge" number.

Answer (score -1):

Using [dwdiff](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dwdiff), output differences with colors and line numbers.

```
echo "Hello world @ $(date)" > file1.txt
echo "Hello world @ $(date)" > file2.txt

dwdiff -c -C 0 -L file1.txt file2.txt
```

[image]